# In Liferay 6.1 CE, how do I let users, in a User Group, view that User Group's web pages?

Tags: glassfish-3, liferay-6

I have a Liferay 6.1 CE installation running on Glassfish 3.1.1.

I have created a few User Groups, and some accompanying private site pages. For example:

User Group

1. Customers

Public Pages

- no pages

Private Pages

1. Welcome
2. Billing
3. Payment

I have created a Post Login Action that pulls the user's User Group and then builds a path from that.

I have assigned a few test users to the 'Customers' user group. But when I log in with one of these customers, I get the following error screen

[image: Access Denied for user]

and the following log message

> INFO: 19:11:40,760 INFO  [PortalImpl:4873] Current URL /en/group/56058 generates >exception: User 29354 is not allowed to access the private pages of group 56059
>
> INFO: 19:11:40,762 INFO  [PortalImpl:4890] User 29354 is not allowed to access the private >pages of group 56059

The user is obviously a member of the User Group

[image: Display of 'Customer' User Group members]

And the Customer User Group's Site allows the "Site Member" role to "View" its pages

[image: User Group Site Permissions]...[image: User Group Site Permissions]

Does anyone have any idea how to allow a user, that is a member of a User Group, to view *that* User Group's private pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new Regular Role e.g. `Customers` and add your UserGroup to this Role as member. Add the View-Permission at your private pages to this Role.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the answer @Mark! I followed your steps and now the Welcome page is showing up. I have a follow up question though. The portlets on this page are displaying a permissions error, and the remaining pages (Billing & Payment) for the User Group are not displaying. I had to assign the "Customers" Role on the page level permissions. Am I going to have to specifically assign the new 'Customer' role to _each_ page _and_ portlet for it to be visible to this User Group's users, or is there a better way?

Comment: The better way you can config permanent Permission for the Role. Control Panel -> Roles -> 'Customer'-Role -> Actions->Define Permissions. Add permanent permission to this role. But then the user with this role have this permission for all Layouts or Portlets of your Portal. You can limit the permission scope to site too.

Comment: Thanks again for the help.  The tip on permanent role permissions did the trick. I can get all of the pages to show up by selecting _Sites_ from the _Add Permissions_ dropdown. Then check the _View_ checkbox under the _Page_ section.  I am unable to limit the scope as you indicated, the site for my _Customer_ User Group doesn't show up on the 'Limit Scope' screen.  I think this is a limitation of Liferay; it doesn't seem to treat User Group Sites as equally as Organization Sites or regular Sites.